# Image crop aspect ratio do not works

Tags: laravel-backpack

Trying to figure out the image crop aspect ratio attribute, but can't make it working.
The code isL

```
protected function addUserFields()
{
    $this->crud->addFields([


        [
            'name'      => 'profile_image', // The db column name
            'label'     => trans('Profile image'), // Table column heading
            'type'      => 'image',
            'upload'    => true,
            'crop'      => true,
            'aspect-ratio' => 1,
           
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s probably because you’re using a dash instead of underscore. It should be:

'aspect_ratio' => 1, // omit or set to 0 to allow any aspect ratio

Please also note what [the docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields) say:

The value for aspect_ratio is a float that represents the ratio of the cropping rectangle height and width. By way of example,

- Square = 1
- Landscape = 2
- Portrait = 0.5

And you can, of course, use any value for more extreme rectangles.